# ServiceStack Swagger UI 500 Error

Tags: servicestack, swagger-ui

I'm getting a 500 error when testing a ServiceStack API using Swagger UI.
Here's the plugin code:

```
    private void InitializePlugins(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
        Plugins.Add(new PostmanFeature());
        Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature()
        {
            RouteSummary =
            {
                {"/resource/Messages", "Manage queue messages." },
                {"/resource/Configurations", "Manage retry configuration a specific Area/Type combo." },
                {"/resource/healthcheck", "Healthcheck endpoint." }
            }
        });
        Plugins.Add(new HealthCheckFeature(container));
        Plugins.Add(new CorrelationIdFeature());
        EnableAuth();
        EnableCors();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you may have conflicting services registered on Swagger’s /resources and /resource Routes. These Routes should be reserved for Swagger, I.e don’t use them for your Services. Also you may want to use the newer OpenApiFeature instead of SwaggerFeature as it implements the newer version of the spec.

Comment: Thank you @mythz!